# How could I make a 2-D map for a set of points, based on their probability distribution?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I want to make a 2-D map and I have a set of data with X and Y as their coordinates and each point has a probability distribution based on one of its properties. 
In somehow I would like to smooth this probability distribution of each point in the x and y coordinate and make a 2-D map based on the maximum and the width of the peak of each point probability distribution.

how could I use python to implement it?

Comment: Seaborn has excellent support for this (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/examples/plotting_distributions.ipynb#Multivariate-density-estimation-with-kdeplot)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this question is going to be closed as it seems way too broad, but I think you are looking for [Kernel Density Estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), or for [Multivariate kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation).

Loosely, each point defines a distribution (the kernel) which when convolved, gives you a "smoothed" version. See the linked article at the picture below for a better example:

[image]

[**Scipy has a Gaussian KDE**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).

Comment: Let's see, if I have for each point a probability distribution of the third component, how could I insert it in the framework of KDE because  it usually works if we assume our probability distribution is one or multi-dimensional Gaussian distribution?

Comment: @Dalek If you read up on KDE, you'll see that at it's core level it simply sums up a sampled kernel centered at each point (Gaussian or otherwise). You could build a fine mesh and sample your kernel at each of your points up to some cutoff. Essentially this is what the other libraries do, they employ tricks for numerical speed for the Gaussian case.